# Collapsible Panels/Regions

Tags: feature-request, code

Too much information can be a bad thing.  If a stack trace isn't helpful to the answer, all it serves to do is clutter up the entire question and deter people from even wanting to read the question.  Other times, the stack trace may hold the answer, but it was omitted because posting it would harm the aesthetic value of the question.

I for instance am admittedly biased towards questions that make me have to read an entire novel to answer a question -- even when the question might be simple.  I open up the question, see 10 pages worth of routines and markup, and quickly go back to find a more condensed question.

I would like to suggest having a collapsible panel `tag` on a question that would allow an extremely long region of code to be condensed.  Then, if I cared about the stack trace, for instance, I could expand the panel to see the entirety of the code.  While newer users wouldn't be versed into doing this, administrative users could easily wrap long code in a region and then collapse it.  It would attract more users to the question and allow more information to be added without having *too much information*  For instance, the first line the a code example could be a special collapse tag, e.g.

```
::Collapsed
[Long Stack Trace]
```

Then, if you actually cared about reading a stack trace, you could just click on the `+` to expand it.  Otherwise, if you knew the answer without needing a drawn out version of the question, you could just answer it.